# How to host laravel 5 project in subfolder of real web server for staging?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am newbie to Laravel. Now I am doing my very first project of Laravel 5. It is a small project.

I already developed it as beta version. Now I need to show it to my client. So I need to do staging.

I have to host it on the subfolder of our company website. For example, I need to host it in {domain}/{project_name} folder. How can I do it properly?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to configure the webserver to point at the .../whatever/{domain}/{project_name}/public directory.

And of course - set proper permissions for storage, run composer install, configure your db and run your migrations, etc.

Comment: So please how to configure it ? I just have the filezilla access

Comment: I have SSH access too

Comment: I don't know what your hosting environment is like. If you have Cpanel access or similar, you should change your document root. Otherwise, you can try to move the files in your /public directory like this guy did : http://www.stephensaw.me/deploy-laravel-on-shared-hosting-with-subdomain/

Comment: No . I do ot have access to it , CPanel.